# Join table where table name is a value in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked with getting some data out of another database not designed by me, so the design cannot be altered.

Looking at the data I need to join a table dynamically based on the value held in another table.

E.G

`SELECT * FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB oN TableA.TBID = TableB.ID LEFT JOIN TableB.TableOffset AS C ON C.TableAID = TableA.ID`

So table B has a column called TableOffset, this holds the name of the table that needs to be joined on as C

(I've tried to do an SQLFIDDLE but the site isn't working with SQL Server ATM)

The issue is there are 112 attribute tables where the data could be, so doing a left join for every one of them would slow down the query I imagine.

So based on the below I would need to get a result set of:

```
| TableAID | TableATitle | AttrTableA21 | AttrTableA22 |
|----------|-------------|--------------|--------------|
|1         |test         | Name         | 2019         |
|2         |test2        | Name 2       | 2016         |
```

Example SQL Code

````
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Title] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [TableBID] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_A](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_B](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_C](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_D](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );  
  INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(1, 'test', 1);
  INSERT INTO TableB VALUES(1, 'ATTR_C');
  INSERT INTO ATTR_C VALUES (1, 1, 'Name', 2019);
  INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(2, 'test2', 2);
  INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (2, 'ATTR_A');
  INSERT INTO ATTR_A VALUES (1, 2, 'Name 2', 2016);
    ```
````

Comment: Hi you have to use dynamic SQL and Execute see at this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That isn't how an RDBMS works I'm afraid. I realise you've said that you can't change the design, however, this type of requirement screams poor design unfortunately, and normally means you need to actually change it. You *do* have a couple of solutions, however, neither are particularly friendly/performant. One is to use Dynamic SQL to query the other table; which you have to do RBAR if you're trying to return data from every/many rows that reference many tables. The other is to include **every** table in your `FROM` clause using a `LEFT JOIN` with an `ON` like `AND B.TableOffset = 'TableC'`.

Comment: So, to expand a little on my final comment `LEFT JOIN TableC C ON B.fID = C.ID AND B.TableOffset = N'TableC' LEFT JOIN TableD D ON B.fId = D.ID AND B.TableOffSet = N'TableD' LEFT ....` you get the idea. This design does also mean that you don't have have foreign key constraints set up, so you could well easily have references to primary keys that no longer exist.

Comment: Hi, thx for the good question with DDL and `INSERT` of test data, with expected output and clear explanation. +1 from my side

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo for the upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were told already, that this approach is the wrong one entirely. But if you have to stick with this, you might try this:

Your test scenario in a new database (carefull, if you use this database name already...)

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE MyTestDb;
GO
USE MyTestDb;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Title] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [TableBID] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_A](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_B](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_C](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATTR_D](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [TableAID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [A21] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [A22] [int] NOT NULL
  );  
  INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(1, 'test', 1);
  INSERT INTO TableB VALUES(1, 'ATTR_C');
  INSERT INTO ATTR_C VALUES (1, 1, 'Name', 2019);
  INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(2, 'test2', 2);
  INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (2, 'ATTR_A');
  INSERT INTO ATTR_A VALUES (1, 2, 'Name 2', 2016);
GO
```

--I create an *inlined table valued function* where all attribute tables are returned as one set using `UNION ALL`
--The engine is smart enough, to avoid the call, if the parameter does not fit.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTheRightSet(@SetKey VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT ID,TableAID,A21,A22 FROM dbo.ATTR_A WHERE @SetKey='ATTR_A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,TableAID,A21,A22 FROM dbo.ATTR_B WHERE @SetKey='ATTR_B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,TableAID,A21,A22 FROM dbo.ATTR_C WHERE @SetKey='ATTR_C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,TableAID,A21,A22 FROM dbo.ATTR_D WHERE @SetKey='ATTR_D'
GO
```

--This is how to use it

```
SELECT TableA.*
      ,TableB.*
      ,TheSet.* 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.TableBID = TableB.ID 
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetTheRightSet(TableB.TableName) TheSet
GO
```

--Clean up (carefull with real data)

```
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE MyTestDb;
```

Comment: I had a suspicion that I would have to do it this way, I was hoping there would be a more elegant way :)  Accepted answer

Comment: @Neo, well, that's quite slick in my eyes... What should be *more elegant* ;-) Btw: You will have to pass the `TableAID` as a second parameter - but you've found this yourself I suppose...

Comment: a "more elegant" way would be to not have to use an inline function with 100+ tables in a union :) instead being able to "parse" the field (much like a $$ in php) would be elegant but please don't let that take away from your response its just a limitation of the system :)